# How to iterate over lists from the middle out

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I would like to iterate over all lists/tuples of length n with elements from -s...s.  Currently I do this with:

```
for k in itertools.product(range(-s,s+1), repeat = n):
    #process k and maybe print out the result
```

However this not useful for me as there are a huge number of such tuples and my code may never terminate.  I would really like to start with the most interesting ones first. In this case the order I would like for the iteration is:

1. All tuples that contain only 0 (there is only one)
2. All tuples that contain only 0, 1 and -1 excluding those tuples we have already seen.
3. All tuples that contain only 0, 1,-1, 2 and-2 excluding those tuples we have already seen.
4. And so on...

How can one do this?

Comment: Split it in half, reverse the first one, and `zip()` them? Not sure I understand what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I would like to iterate over the lists in the order I described. For each list I iterate over I am going to run some function and sometimes print out the result. Overall the code may never terminate which is why I want to do them in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
import itertools

def sorted_tuples(length, max_s):
    nums = [0]
    for s in range(max_s):
        for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nums, length):
            if s in p or -s in p:
                yield p
        nums = [-(s+1)] + nums + [s+1]

for i in sorted_tuples(3,2):
    print(i)

# prints the following
(0, 0, 0)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, 0)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, 0, 0)
(-1, 0, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: There must be a bug. If I do `for i in sorted_tuples(9,4): ` and look at the output the values range from -3 to 3.   I should therefore get 7^9 = 40353607 lines of output but instead I get 5005.

Answer (score 1):

So your code to be done with the lists in much more expensive than sorting?

Then you can sort the list of these lists with a `key` argument. The things you call list are tuples indeed, right? At least in my python 2.7 itertools. I would convert them to arrays, since I think you cannot use abs otherwise. Then the sorting function is:

```
lists.sort(key = lambda t: np.max(np.abs(np.array(t))))
```

does this work fast enough?

Comment: There are (2s+1)^n different lists. I can't afford to make them all and then sort them. This is why I want to iterate over them in a sensible order.

Comment: so you want to *make* them in a sensible order. Then why dont you start with s=0, make the lists, save them and then substract them from the s=1 lists (you can make a `set` and substract sets, since the tuples are immutable)

Comment: Two things. I don't want to store a huge number of tuples/lists and second the subtraction will be expensive. It would be much better just to iterate over them in the right order.

Comment: you dont need to substract, by the way - I see now, that they are ordered so, that the old tuples are in the middle; so you just need the length of the old list and can then slice

Comment: You are still making the same lists over and over again this way.